# Pandas read_excel UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, pandas

The following codes creates the error

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte**

```
with open(file_path) as excel_file:
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code solved the issue

```
with open(file_path,mode="rb") as excel_file:
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
```